# how to mount using ceph-fuse and specify IP in /etc/fstab

Tags: linux, ceph, fstab

My server configuration is as follows

```
A ceph cluster server(10.1.1.138)
B ceph cluster server(10.1.1.54)
C ceph client (10.1.1.238)
```

I could mount using the following ceph-fuse command

```
sudo ceph-fuse -k /etc/ceph/ceph.client.admin.keyring -m 10.1.1.138:6789 /mnt/mycephfs/
```

But I don't know how to mount with /etc/fstab

The following setting is failed.

```
sudo vim /etc/fstab
10.1.1.138:/    /mnt/mycephfs   fuse.ceph name=admin,secretfile=/home/ec2-user/admin.secret,noatime    0       2


sudo mount -a
```

-> Syntax error occured.

Using kerner driver mount instead of ceph-fuse is work.

```
 sudo vim /etc/fstab
    10.1.1.138:/    /mnt/mycephfs  ceph name=admin,secretfile=/home/ec2-user/admin.secret,noatime    0       2


    sudo mount -a
```

-> success

IP specification can not be found even in official tutorial

http://docs.ceph.com/docs/kraken/cephfs/fstab/

I don't know why there is no way to specfiy IP of each cluster server in offical tutorial.

If it could be mount without specifying IP, I would like to know its principle.

Am i misunderstanding something?

let me know there is something to be a hint.

Thank you for reading my question.

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on either http://superuser.com OR http://serverfault.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: oh, or https://unix.stackexchange.com . Good luck.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.